# Unit testing UITextField with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, reactive-cocoa

I'm writing a unit test that ensures changes in a `UITextField` are reflected in my app's ViewModel. ReactiveCocoa4 is being used to bind the text field to the view model.

```
func testViewToViewModelCommunication(){
    viewController.originalTextField.text="test"
    XCTAssertEqual(viewController.originalTextField.text, viewModel.originalText) // viewModel.originalText is a String?
}
```

The test fails. Because the app is working in practice, I believe this testing code doesn't trigger the appropriate ReactiveCocoa methods. My guess is that the `="test"` line isn't the proper way to manually set the text in ReactiveCocoa. What's the right way to do this?

EDIT:
Here's how the text field and corresponding ViewModel variable are bound:

```
originalTextField.rac_textSignal().subscribeNextAs{
    [weak self] (text:String) -> () in
    self!.viewModel?.originalText=text
}
```

The `subscribeNextAs` method is just a `RACSignal` extension to clean things up a little:

```
extension RACSignal {
    func subscribeNextAs<T>(nextClosure:(T) -> ()) -> () {
        self.subscribeNext {
            (next: AnyObject!) -> () in
            let nextAsT = next as! T
            nextClosure(nextAsT)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, what is `viewModel.originalText` and how is that supposed to be set?  Second, you might need (probably) `XCTAssertEqualObjects`.  And third, unit testing maybe shouldn't be testing UI like this...

Comment: @nhgrif Thanks for the comment, question has been updated. (`viewModel.originalText` is just a `String?`)

Comment: Adding a comment within the code (which doesn't even fit on the screen without scroll) doesn't help this question.  You didn't address *any* of my three points.

Comment: Please show us the rest of your code. Namely the piece where you set up the binding between the view model and the text field.

Comment: Hi @TamásZahola, the binding code's now been added to the question.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the `subscribeNextAs` block and see if it gets executed.

Comment: Yup, it gets executed. The binding code works just fine in practice, it's just that this test function doesn't trigger the binding properly for some reason.

Comment: I meant put a breakpoint there while executing the unit test.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the line gets hit during the unit test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95937/discussion-between-tamas-zahola-and-rogare).